# Undeclared identifier but is declared

Tags: c++

I wrote this code :

```
#define HIDE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

HIDE int main(){
    int x = 10;
    int z = 5;
    int c;

    c = call1(x,z);
}

HIDE int call1(int a,int b)
{
    int r;
    r = a+b;
    return r;
}
```

But when I try to compile it I get this error:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'call1'
c=call1(x,z);

I already looked here but have not found similar problems.
If it does matters, I am using Xcode to compile the code.

Comment: You need to declare it *before* you use it.

Comment: Can't see the reason why any downvotes are applied here, besides the tagging is (was) a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Undeclared identifier but is declared

No, it isn't. Your identifier is *defined*, not *declared*. This is a common source of confusion. Declaration of an identifier means to give it a unique signature that can be referred to in the following code lines. Definition means to give it a certain value/implementation. A *definition* implies *declaration* for the following code.

***At least an identifiers complete declaration must have been seen before first usage.***

That said you can simply put a declaration for your function before `main()`

```
HIDE int call1(int a,int b);
```

or just change your code to

```
HIDE int call1(int a,int b) {
    int r;
    r= a+b;
    return r;
}

HIDE int main() {
    int x = 10;
    int z = 5;
    int c;

    c=call1(x,z);
}
```

and put the *definition* (which actually implies the *declaration*) before `main()` to have a forward declaration for your function.

I'm going to cite the [current standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) section 3.1 here

> #### 3.1 Declarations and deﬁnitions [basic.def]
>
> 1 A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or redeclare names
>   introduced by previous declarations. If so, the declaration speciﬁes the interpretation and attributes of these
>   names. A declaration may also have eﬀects including:
>    — a static assertion (Clause 7),
>    — controlling template instantiation (14.7.2),
>    — use of attributes (Clause 7), and
>    — nothing (in the case of an empty-declaration).
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you , so all has to happen before the point where its called ?

Comment: @user3452589 _'... so all has to happen before ...'_ The _declaration_ yes. The _definition_ can be elsewhere, even in a different file.

Comment: The explanation of defined vs. declared is not quite correct. I think rather than talking talking about that distinction it would be better to discuss how in C++, unlike many other languages, code can only use declarations that precede it. This is because C++ compilers conceptually process source one line at a time and can't use information from lines they haven't processed yet (for the most part).

Comment: @bames53 What's actually incorrect please? Could you give some more useful pointers? When I said _signature_ I didn't mean _function signature_ presumably.

Comment: The main thing that was missing was that definitions are also declarations, so it doesn't generally make sense to say that a symbol is defined but not declared. Mention of definitions also being declarations has been added now, (although the earlier statement of "defined, not declared" remains). The bottom line, IMO, is that the definition/declaration distinction is less relevant to this question than the C++ concept of 'visibility', where declarations have to come before usage (for the most part).

Comment: @bames53 Feel free to edit or adding another answer. I have the feeling this looks as a goof canonical for applying to further questions.

Comment: "At least an identifiers complete declaration must have been seen before first usage." - declarations of incomplete types can be used in some ways

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
HIDE int call1(int a,int b);  // pre define 

HIDE int main(){
    int x = 10;
    int z = 5;
    int c;

    c = call1(x,z);
}

HIDE int call1(int a,int b)
{
    int r;
    r = a+b;
    return r;
}
```